# DXA Component template metadata - Region Name not excluding the module name

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-java, dxa-1.4

It looks like there is some problem regarding the automatically Region Name setup on empty component metadata field.

I currently have this setup on my component template:
[image]

From my understanding the Region Name should then be TelenorHeaderStart (with excluded module name).

When I run the code I get this problem where the module name is not excluded after all:
[image]

That in the end creates a bug where region is not found (returned null) when this code is run (in RegionTag.java) where name variable is equal to "TelenorHeaderStart":

```
if (parentRegion != null) {
    region = parentRegion.getRegions().get(name);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug, or intended behavior?
I found out that if I set the Region Name in the meta data field to "TelenorHeaderStart" it works as is should be. But then there seem to be something wrong regarding that you cant leave this field empty, and the current message displayed on the metadata schema.

Just trying to figure out if I have something wrong with my setup.

Comment: I don't understand the issue you are having with the work-around of explicitly specifying the Region Name...

Comment: Okay, well I guess it's not really an issue then if that work-around is the correct approach. I just was wondering why the empty region name was not working, and if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Ah, OK. You mean that the field description suggests that this work-around should not be needed. That's correct; it should not be needed (see my Answer below). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a bug. I vaguely remember such an issue in DXA Java. If you're observing it in DXA 1.4 still, it might have been fixed in DXA 1.5.